Low space in root file system
I wish to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04. I have a problem with 'low space in root file system'. How do I create more space in the root file system

This question is similar to: How to resize partitions?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You've provided few specifics; for starters you mention release but not if you're using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server etc...   The release has minimum disk requirements for a reason documented; but the easiest fix is just to re-size your partition(s).  Anything else requires more detail (eg. deleting apps; reducing log sizes etc)  FYI:  I've got two systems now I want to release-upgrade but have only ~3.5-4GB free, where I won't do it until I have >5.5GB free... but requirements vary on what apps & what needs to be updated; as not package types will change...

Thanks. I've been using Ubuntu since 2004 and have always been able to upgrade to new LTS releases easily. It's the first time now that I face this 'low root file system' problem. I will try the resize option if thats what is tobe done.

Ubuntu after 17.04 increased the minimum disk requirements, firstly as the return to GNOME (3) requires more space, secondly the snap package requirements are also a little different.. If your system pre-dates 17.10; it may very possibly not meet current requirements (assuming Desktop; as Server didn't experience the same changes; you don't specify what Ubuntu product).

I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop are both used on laptops... many people use old laptops as low-powered servers; so Ubuntu 22.04 LTS doesn't define which product... as Server & Desktops have very different requirements (Desktops require more space!)

Sorry, I should have mentioned Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop is what I'm using

This question is similar to: Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
